# My wave animation is not working

Tags: animation

So I’m just trying to create a cartoon ocean from a YouTube tutorial , and I went to apply the Wave animation, but nothing is happening, so just trying to figure out what to do ..

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! The more detail you can give us the better. What have you tried so far? What are you expecting to happen vs what's happening? You can also edit your post to include screenshots or gifs, which can be very helpful in showing the problem.

Comment: and maybe share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/